# doubt about Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

the text of the exercise says: "Consider the following sets: $A=\{1,2,5\}$, $B=\{+,*\}$. Determine $A \times B$, $B \times A$, $B^2=B \times B$."

I would say that for example $A \times B =\{(1,+),(2,+),(5,+),(1,*),(2,*),(5,*)\}$ but it just doesn't make any sense to me to have an ordered pair made of a number and the sign of an operation. Is my answer right? Thank you :)

Comment: Your answer is right.  Ordered pairs can use **any** objects.

Comment: In this example, it helps if you stop thinking of `1` as a number, and `+` as an operation.  `1` is an object.  `+` is also an object.  They are just things which live inside some sets.  They are completely arbitrary symbols, with no other intrinsic meaning.

Comment: We have no idea what the symbols represent as they are just members of sets. It could be that $+=\{a,b,c,d\}$ or $+=\mathbb R$ or anything really. $+$ and $*$ are just symbols that represent some mathematical object.

Comment: To emphasize this point... not only could things like $+$ or $*$ be elements of sets... *other sets could be elements of sets*!  Anything that can be mathematically defined can be an element of a set and is just as valid to appear as any other object, number or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is fine. Yes, $"+"$ and $"*"$ are often used to represent binary operations on sets. However, here they are just elements of some set.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification :)